# ItemRegister Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, iteration

I am trying to create an item register to register items inside the rooms.

In room class i have a

```
  /**
     * Gets item description
     */
    public ArrayList<Item> getItem()
    {
      return items;
    }
```

and in item register I currently have

```
public class ItemRegister
{
    private HashMap<String,Item> items;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ItemRegister
     */
    public ItemRegister()
    {
        items = new HashMap<String,Item>();

    }
    /**
     * register items in hashMap
     */
    public void register(Item a)
    {
        items.put(a.getDescription(),a);


    }

     public void register(ArrayList<Item> a)
    {
       Iterator<Item> i = a.iterator();
       while (i.hasNext())
       {
        Room room = i.next();
         if (room.getItem() != null && room.getItem().equals(a))
        {

        }
        else{

        }
       }

    }
}
```

I am trying to complete the iterator to cycle through room and if it finds an item inside the room it will register it by placing it into hashMap

Comment: And what errors do you see? what are you expecting to see instead?  can you provide more information on where you are getting stuck?  --- Initially I see that you are iterating over an `ArrayList<item> a` but you are getting this `Room room = i.next();`  - since this is an array of `items` you will get an error if you try to cast it into `room`

Comment: Thats the thing.. I am not exactly sure how to write it.. This is just what I attempted.. I want it to cycle through the rooms, looking for item objects. if it finds them, then it should add them to hashMap

Comment: but nowhere in your code you have a definition of `Room`... if you need to cycle through all the rooms, why not pass a list of `rooms` instead of `items`?

Comment: I see what you saying.. but i just cannot get my head around how to write this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hopefully this will be enough to get you going:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ItemRegister{

    public static void main(String []args){
        ItemRegister ir = new ItemRegister();
    }

    // storing items registered here
    private HashMap<String,Item> items;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ItemRegister
     */
    public ItemRegister(){
        items = new HashMap<String,Item>();

        ArrayList<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<>();
        roomList.add( new Room( new Item("Item A") ) );
        roomList.add( new Room( new Item("Item B") ) );
        roomList.add( new Room( new Item("Item C") ) );
        roomList.add( new Room( new Item("Item D") ) );


        System.out.println( "Size of Registered Items:" + items.size() ); 

        // Register only A item
        Item aItem = new Item("Item A");
        register( roomList, aItem );

        /// print whatever is in the register
        System.out.println( "Size of Registered Items:" + items.size() ); 
        System.out.println( "Registered Items:" ); 

        for( Item item : items.values() ){
            System.out.println( item.getDescription() ); 
        }
        System.out.println( "---- end ----" ); 

        // Register B item too
        Item bItem = new Item("Item B");        
        register( roomList, bItem );

        /// print whatever is in the register
        System.out.println( "Size of Registered Items:" + items.size() ); 
        System.out.println( "Registered Items:" ); 

        for( Item item : items.values() ){
            System.out.println( item.getDescription() ); 
        }
        System.out.println( "---- end ----" ); 
    }

    /**
     * register items in hashMap
     */
    public void register(Item a){
        items.put(a.getDescription(), a);
        System.out.println( "Registered an Item" ); 
    }

    public void register(ArrayList<Room> roomList, Item a){
        Iterator i = roomList.iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Room room = (Room)i.next();

            if (room.getItem() != null && room.getItem().equals(a)){
                register( room.getItem() );
            }
        }
    }

    /* class Item */
    protected class Item{
        private String description;

        Item(String description){
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getDescription(){
            return this.description;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Item)) {
            return false;
        }

        Item item = (Item) o;

        if (!description.equals(item.description)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    }

    /* class Room */
    protected class Room{
        private Item item;

        Room( Item item ){
            this.item = item;
        }

        public Item getItem(){
            return this.item;
        }
    }
}
```